# Can a role be created with limits on which branches can be managed?

Tags: azure-devops

For separation of duty purposes, my company has a policy that says developers involved in a change cannot be involved in the push of that code to staging or production, so we have a release team that reviews pull requests to those branches and pushes to the relevant environment.

The team leads want to be able to define policies for the dev and test branches because those branches have their own dedicated environments.

Our Azure admins are still learning Azure, so if someone can point to documentation that either explicitly states it is not possible to allow this, or documentation that describes how to set this up.

Edit: To clarify (hopefully), I'll put it in outline form.

- Developers can create any branch and push and merge to and from it however they wish. Developers cannot manage policies on any branch.
- Team leads for that team can define policies on specific branches (dev and test branches) but cannot on other branches (stg and prod branches).
- Release Team can define policies on any branch, but specifically will manage stg and prod branches.

The first and last conditions are working. I can't figure out how to tell the azure admins to give the team leads permissions to manage policies **only on specific branches**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project Settings -- Repositories, select the branch and set the `Edit policy` permission for the Team leads:

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something here? This would allow the team leads to edit policies for *all* branches, correct? I don't see a way here to restrict a role to specific branches.

Comment: I *am* missing something. Thank you. That answers my quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this using a branch policy.

Developers would work on and push changes to a feature branch. When the code is ready they would create a pull request into the next branch in your pipeline.

It can be set up so that only your release team can approve the pull requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies-overview?view=azure-devops

Comment: I didn't explain myself well enough. I will add to my question to clarify.